# custom routing not working in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating a friendly URL so i have crete route in routeconfig file as follows

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "ShowUser",                                              // Route name
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
           defaults: new { controller = "UserGroupEdit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
```

and action link as follows

```
  <a href="@Url.Action( "Index", "ShowUser")" onclick="javascript:onBegin()">View</a>
```

But it is not working giving runtime error "The resource cannot be found."

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /ShowUser/Index

Comment: Default route should work even if the way you accessing custom route is not correct. Ensure that `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);` is inside `Application_Start` event. Could you show Controller and Action method?

Comment: Here is the names "UserGroupEditController" and action is Index

Comment: @C.jacking did any of the responses answered your question?

Comment: @MaximoDominguez nothing worked it actually effects my ajax calls if i change the route, so i did the silly thing to change the controller name manually.

Answer (score 2):

Default route and you custom route have identical structure, so default one will always be used because it is declared first.
Im guessing you are getting error because in code you are referring to ShowUser, but instead you should use name of the controller: UserGroupEdit.

```
<a href="@Url.Action( "Index", "UserGroupEdit")" onclick="javascript:onBegin()">View</a>
```

Comment: No actually my requirement is to give user friendly URL instead of UserGroupEdit/Index in url bar it must show ShowUser/Index in bar.

Comment: @C.jacking see my answer above for a solution

Comment: You can use Route attribute then: place [Route("ShowUser")] to wanted action and as link use <a href="@Url.RouteUrl( "ShowUser",  new { controller = "UserGroupEdit", action = "Index" })" onclick="javascript:onBegin()">View</a>

Comment: @OgnjenBabic suggestion was looking good but still not working

Comment: The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404

Comment: Did you delete default routing? As i said, it is greedy and it will match request for ShowUser before your custom routing. I created test mvc app and I managed to create your custom routing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a friendly route you can do something like this

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
      name: "ShowUser",                                              // Route name
       url: "ShowUser/index/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
       defaults: new { controller = "UserGroupEdit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }  // Parameter defaults
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Auth", action = "LogIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

in your `cshtml`

```
@Url.Action( "Index", "UserGroupEdit")
```

Comment: No actually my requirement is to give user friendly URL instead of UserGroupEdit/Index in url bar it must show ShowUser/Index in bar.

Comment: In both if the options I offer the url shows "showuser/index"

Comment: If i rename controller name then i need to change in mutliple places that is why i am using custom url

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UrlHelper.RouteUrl` helper method which allows you to specify the route name:

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ShowUser", new { action = "Index" })" onclick="javascript:onBegin()">View</a>
```

RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ShowUser",
    url: "ShowUser/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "UserGroupEdit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Reference [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.routeurl(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.RouteUrl%28System.String,System.Object%29)

Comment: nope still not working. it is generating "http://localhost:52155/ShowUser" and error loading page "Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found. "

Comment: Update your routeconfig as shown above. 
You can also use `Route` attribute to achieve what you are looking for. Look at @Win's answer